# Datatables ocultar colunas no modo responsivo

Tags: jquery-datatables, datatable

Seria possível mostrar apenas as colunas desejadas e todas as outras no modo de expandir com o datatables.js e o plugin responsive?
O que quero fazer é mostrar apenas X colunas na tela quando carrega a tabela, e deixar as outras ocultas pra serem vistas quando expandir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o datatables.js você pode definir a prioridade de exibição das colunas marcando as células do cabeçalho (tag th) com "data-priority". Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-priority="1">First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Aqui tem outros exemplos de como fazer isso:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/priority

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/auto.html